# When do I fight Satan?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I killed mom (heart) 4 times but still there's no Satan at final.

When do I fight Satan? What should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the wiki article about [Sheol](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Sheol) says, you can enter Sheol and fight Satan if you get a devil room after defeating Mom's Heart. Once you beat Mom's Heart 10 times, you will always be given the option to enter Sheol.